# Where is the section with the top questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions

I like some of the changes in the new stackoverflow/stackexchange site but I miss the section with the top questions (when you clicked on the stackexchange name) - it was like my morning newspaper! Can I find the top questions somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Top questions are available on the [main Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/questions) - from here you can see hot questions and filter specific questions based on tag or site.

Additionally, hot questions are shown on the homepage of each Stack Exchange site in the side bar, where "Recent Tags" used to be;

[image]

Comment: Thank you for info! The -1 wasn't really necessary... the questions aren't really the same...

Comment: [I didn't downvote you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8cEf6.png).